# Sharepoint workflow deployed, but not showing up

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-2010

I have a sharepoint workflow that I created in VS2010, and I've deployed it through the web interface to my sharepoint 2010 environment.  The ui says that it's been deployed, and it is activated on my site.  If I look in my site features, I do see the entry for it and everything looks good.  But when I go to any of my lists to try to add it in, it isn't showing up...  it has to be something easy that I'm missing, does anyone have any thoughts?  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did finally find what the issue was...  for me, when I went to the workflow settings on a list, I had to hit the drop down for item type and choose item instead of all.  Once I did that, the workflow showed up for me to select it.

[image]

Comment: This did not work for me... SharePoint 2013 workflow developed through VS 2012. I cant find it anywhere :(

Comment: I had reusable Workflow for Document Content Type, so it was not listing as default one is for List.

Comment: I had to do this too. Shame that is isn't automatic. I may have to script this in PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the List | Worklfow Settings page and select the link "Remove Workflow"
When that loads, see if the workflow is set to "Allow New Instances", if not, make it so and see if that gets things running for you again.